# crash dumps missing nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I'm developing an application (on Windows now but I'd like to have a mac version as well) using angularjs and node webkit.

It happens that my application crashes but I don't know why. So I thought I should check the dump file generated as precised here : https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Crash-dump

So here is my code :

```
// Load native UI library
var ngui = require('nw.gui');

ngui.App.setCrashDumpDir("logs");

// Get the current window
var nwin = ngui.Window.get();
// show devtools to debug
nwin.showDevTools();

onload = function() {
    nwin.show();
    nwin.maximize();
}

ngui.App.crashBrowser();
```

I've put the last line to find a crash report but I'm unable to find any in the logs folder of my application.
Why ?

Thank you

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm doing the same thing and the dump files are not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging in the source and found the reason. It appears that setCrashDumpDir has been disabled in 0.12 for whatever reason.

In [breakpad_win.cc](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/blob/master/src/breakpad_win.cc#L778), SetSetCrashDumpPath should have been called from [app.cc (nw.app module)](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/blob/master/src/api/app/app.cc#L182).

[The commit responsible for this was authored by GnorTech and has been disabled since Aug. 29th, 2014](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/commit/d1dee800e65947fc0610943279a3976ff8c6962c).

I'm going to raise a bug report for this.

EDIT:
Looks like a bug report already exists. https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/3226